# Check Checkboxes in Grouped Table Rows Only

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm enhancing a standard html table with the Datatables jQuery plugin. What I have is a list of invoices which are grouped by what is known as a "job" in this particualr industry. So, I  have a job description on the "grouping" table row and a list of the individual invoices within that job on subsequent table rows until we hit the next "grouping" table row that corresponds with a different job. In the last table cell on each of these table rows I have a checkbox. See image below for a basic example (sorry, had to sanitize for client).

[image: Table Row Checkboxes]

When a user checks checkbox "#1" (see image), I want the subsequent checkboxes to be checked through "#6". So, in effect, I want the checkbox in each "grouping" row to only check the checkboxes that belong to its respective group.

**HTML Code (sanitized and simplified)**

```
<!--Grouping Row 1-->
<tr id="group-id-example_insertjobname">
<td colspan="11" data-group="-b-insertjobname" data-group-level="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<!--Grouping Row 1-->

<tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="pay">
<input type="checkbox" name="PI0" class="Invoice Open" value="">
</td>
</tr>

<tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="pay">
<input type="checkbox" name="PI1" class="Invoice Open" value="">
</td>
</tr>

<tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="pay">
<input type="checkbox" name="PI2" class="Invoice Open" value="">
</td>
</tr>

<!--Grouping Row 2-->
<tr id="group-id-example_insertjobname">
<td colspan="11" data-group="-b-insertjobname" data-group-level="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<!--Grouping Row 2-->
```

**jQuery Function**

```
 $(function() {
     var ischecked = false;
     $('[id^="checkall"]').click(function(e) {
         e.stopPropagation();   
         e.preventDefault();
         if (ischecked === false) {
             $(".pay input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
                 ischecked = true;
         } else {
             $(".pay input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
             ischecked = false;
         }
     });
});
```

I get why this doesn't work. I'm targeting the .pay selector when a grouping checkbox is clicked, and that selector is common to all table cells beneath all grouping levels. I just don't know where to go from here. I looked at nextUntil(), but not sure exactly how to implement that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its simplest, I'd suggest:

```
// bind the change event-handler to checkboxes with the class 'change':
$('input[type="checkbox"].check').on('change', function() {
  // cache the changed checkbox:
  var check = this;
  // find the closest 'tr' element:
  $(check).closest('tr')
  // find the all the subsequent 'tr' elements until we find a 'tr' with an id:
  .nextUntil('tr[id]')
  // find the checkboxes inside of those 'tr' elements:
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  // set the checked property equal to state of the changed checkbox:
  .prop('checked', check.checked);
});
```

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"].check').on('change', function() {
  var check = this;
  $(check).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr[id]').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', check.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="group-id-example_insertjobname">
      <td colspan="11" data-group="-b-insertjobname" data-group-level="0">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--Grouping Row 1-->

    <tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pay">
        <input type="checkbox" name="PI0" class="Invoice Open" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pay">
        <input type="checkbox" name="PI1" class="Invoice Open" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pay">
        <input type="checkbox" name="PI2" class="Invoice Open" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!--Grouping Row 2-->
    <tr id="group-id-example_insertjobname">
      <td colspan="11" data-group="-b-insertjobname" data-group-level="0">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!--Grouping Row 2-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: This works well, thanks! It's very easy to understand and well commented. I appreciate that. One issue that popped up is with the default behavior of the grouping row. When it is clicked, the default behavior is to collapse and expand the row to reveal the invoices within that job. Of course, when we check the checkbox on the grouping row, your function runs beautifully, David, but the group also expands and collapses.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly each set of grouped rows has the same data attribute on it. If that is the case then you just need to get the group off the parent row and set them like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^="checkall"]').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();   
        e.preventDefault();
        var thisGroup = $(this).closest('tr').data('group');
        var groupCheckboxes = $('tr[data-group="' + thisGroup + '"]').find('input:checkbox');
        groupCheckboxes.prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Anduril. In this case, we would want to target the data-group attribute on the td, right? I made that modification, but the checkboxes are still not checking.